# Called Dr. in government setting?

Tags: professionalism, work-environment, united-states, gender

I work in local government (law enforcement) in the US, where titles are pretty important. I am a civilian supervisor with a doctorate degree. No one else there has this degree. I completed it two years ago. Is it unreasonable to be referred to as Dr. in a professional setting? Don’t know if it makes a difference but I am a female in a highly male industry.

For example, we had an awards ceremony that certain supervisors spoke at. The Chief of Police referred to them with their title, such as Lieutenant Camp, Major Short, but I was referred to as Jen Smith (my name is Jennifer). Even in the email previously about it, the Chief called everyone by their title and me as Supervisor Smith.

The year before he called me Dr. Smith. Even other emails that come to me refer to people’s titles except for me.

I know typically only people in academic settings are called Dr. except for where titles are used, and they are used pretty strongly at my place of employment. I am five years from retirement and have been with the organization for over 20 years. Originally, I got the doctorate because I thought I could make a difference, but now I don’t even care because I do not think I am taken seriously. Almost everything I do is questioned. I have the doctorate designation in my work e-mail signature.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: I understand you're frustrated here, but we need to understand what your goal is to be able to help you - do you want advice on how to approach people to get them to use your title? Do you want a reality check as to whether you're making a mountain out of a molehill? Do you want something else?

Comment: Basically if I am making a mountain out of a molehill. Am I being unreasonable to expect the same amount of respect that others are given?

Comment: Clearly you should be given the same amount of respect as everyone else, that's basic decency. But will things actually be any different if people call you "Doctor"... and keep on questioning what you do?

Comment: Have you spoken to the Chief and asked them why they did not refer to you as Dr.?

Comment: It's not clear to me if this person has never called you Dr. Smith, or if they actually did a year ago but now they stopped doing it.

Comment: Were other people referred to just by name, or only you?

Comment: What do you hope to achieve by posting this here?

Comment: It looks like it would help to clarify what country you are working in, since it seems common practice varies. Also I’m not sure it matters but what is your doctorate in? If it’s criminal justice lr something else law-enforcement related then I think that’s more relevant than if it’s a doctorate in music theory.

Comment: Which country are you from? I had the same issue in France, but the law was on my side. But I still had to go through some: you are not a medical doctor, that is unjustified pride, yadi yada.... I have the law on my side, and you shall please address me as Dr. on official documents, thank you.

Comment: Law enforcement agencies are typically organized along paramilitary lines and thus use _rank_ as a matter of course.  Ranks form a separate title structure - different from say nobility where you use "Sir", "Lord", etc.  But also different from academia.  It would be instructive to compare to actual medical doctor in military service: If I understand that correctly medical doctors in military service are referred to by rank only, not Dr Lt Jameson or Lt Dr Jameson.  Just Lt Jameson.

Comment: There's a slightly implication that you're in the US, but can you confirm in the question? Answers are starting to make assumptions

Comment: I am in the United States. My doctorate is in Leadership.

Comment: Solarflare, I think I am just wanting some perspective.

Comment: cdkMoose, I was the only one referred to name, and it is my nickname.

Comment: As several people already said, knowing your country is quite relevant. For example, the title "Dr" for "doctor" in Italy is not an exclusive attribution to PhDs, but also to master-level graduates: for example I have got a master-level degree in engineering and I could rightfully (and legally) be called Dr.Donati here.

Comment: Chris H, thank you. I edited it.

Comment: DarkCygnus, he referred to me as Dr. Smith the year before and people clapped at it.

Comment: DarkCygnus, he referred to me as Dr. Smith the year before and people clapped at it.

Comment: @Jennifer thanks for clarifying. Could you perhaps enhance on the nature of that ceremony? was is special or important for the Chief?

Comment: @DarkCygnus, it was a yearly award ceremony for Officer of the Year, Detective of the Year, and Dispatcher of the Year. I am a dispatch supervisor.

Comment: Btw this is a kind note that it may not be advisable to use your real name (Jennifer Smith, *Dr.* Jennifer Smith in fact) here or anywhere online.

Comment: @sf02 I have not said anything to him.

Comment: Why do you care if people call you doctor or not?

Answer (score 39):

"Dr." in a civilian setting tends to refer to medical doctors (MD, not PhD).  Of the people I know who have PhDs (and there are quite a few, both male and female), I don't think once have I ever heard any of them referred to as Dr. except ironically.  The reason primarily being that if you are a Dr. then people believe you have medical expertise, because that's how most people interact with people titled "doctor".

The exception to this being if you are working directly in a field where your doctorate is important.  Academia being the major one; if you're a PhD in a field, that means something when you are doing work or research in that field, as opposed to if you are not a PhD.  In that case, it's important to be called Dr.

From your question, it seems like you are working in law enforcement.  The other titles you mentioned are law enforcement rank titles, like Lieutenant and Major; Dr. is not a law enforcement rank and is thus not the same.

As you are not (don't seem to be) a medical doctor, it is, in my opinion, unusual if people were to call you Dr. outside of academia.  My suggestion is to not make a huge issue out of this, unless your work domain is academic.

Comment: Or she could be a medical examiner, in which case, calling her a Doctor would be quite appropriate.

Comment: That's perhaps why OP was called "Supervisor Jennifer" as that is a title relevant to mention in law enforcement.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk As far as I'm aware, medical examiners are generally medical doctors (though this can vary by jurisdiction).

Comment: I upvoted because I agree with the intent of this answer, but I disagree with the facts. I have many friends who have a PhD, and academia is actually the only professional place where their name is ***never*** prefixed with "Dr.".

Comment: Not everyone works in the United States - and norms are _very_ different in different cultures.  Referring to the OP as Frau Doktor Schmidt would absolutely be the norm in Germany; failing to do so would be rude.

Comment: I think this answer would be more helpful with an indication of the cultural/geographic context – you write "in a civilian setting" but a civilian setting in the USA is different in this regard to a civilian setting in the UK, in India, in Germany, etc..

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica: Only in a formal setting. Fortunately use of titles in Austria and Germany is getting less and less (partially this is because MSc and PhD are such a mouthful).

Comment: I had always understood that the USA was one of the few places where the "Dr." title _was_ used. Also, I was never called "Dr" in academia, nor was anyone else (when working in Academia, most people in a given room will likely be PhDs, we don't make a big deal out of it) and now that I work in industry, it is only American colleagues who call me so. Admittedly, they only do so when introducing me to clients and my PhD is indeed relevant to what I do, so it could just be a way of making me sound more important to impress the clients, but still.

Comment: This answer is absolutely wrong. Perhaps the author has confused "a doctor", which would always refer to a medical doctor in American English, with the title "Dr.", which refers to anyone with a doctorate. Personally, I don't use titles, but if you're going to use them, it's aggressively rude to mis-title a person.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica Don't get me started on the use of titles in Germany. Its weird. I've got a proper Bsc in Computer Science and in Germany I'm by law forbidden to use the equivalent Diplom-Ingenieur for the very simple fact that the German Ministry of Education has  a mistake in their database of recognized titles. My fellow students that graduated a year earlier or later are recognized. It just the class of 1992 which isn't in their system. Been a major hassle when applying for jobs in Germany. Was not eligible because I "wasn't qualified".

Comment: @Tonny Isn't B.Sc. given after 3 years? Dipl.Ing. was given after 5 years like the M.Sc. Italian universities gave title dottore after 5 years

Comment: @Michael You say "fortunately", I quite like it actually.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler Dutch "ing." or "drs."  (equivalent to bsc) can be 3, but is mostly 4 years depending on exact field of study (4 in my case). "Ir" or "Dr" (equivalent Msc) takes 2 (or 3) years more. That is the case in all European countries these days. Got standardized beginning of this millennium. Before that there was quite a lot of variation. But the weird thing is that my fellow students got a Dipl-Ing in Germany even though we are officially classified in the rest of Europe as Bsc.

Comment: @dbmag9 I am not sworn law enforcement, but rather a dispatch supervisor. Sorry, I should have been more clear.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica - I worked in Germany as a software dev, and I referred to my colleague with PhD as "yo Steve!". Not everyone is uptight about this nonsense even in a humorless country like Germany.

Comment: @Davor But when the client has a PhD you address them as Herr Doktor. Don't you?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler - I never had to deal with clients, and even if I did it would be in English since I don't speak German well enough to have a conversation. But I guess, maybe? If he introduced himself like that, perhaps, but in software dev the culture is very informal and it's common to mostly use first names only, not even last name, but just straight up "Hi I'm Davor. And you? John. Hello John, how are you doing?" Perhaps some Germans found that off-putting, but I never had anyone complain.

Answer (score 13):

I think it varies by the field you work in.  Using that title is usually to reflect you position in the organizational hierarchy.  In some job types, having a doctorate is important to that hierarchy and others it is not.

Is there a place in your hierarchy that Dr. fits?  I'm not sure where I would place it in the Chief, Major, Lieutenant hierarchy and Supervisor would seem to fit in better.

I work with a number of people who have a Ph.D. We don't refer to any of them as Dr., because it doesn't mean anything in our hierarchy.  In fact most of them are at the lowest rung of the hierarchy.

Answer (score 6):

There's only two situations in which it is typically considered appropriate to call someone "Doctor" when speaking verbally.

The first is a medical doctor who is acting at the time in a professional medical capacity, or being referred to in that capacity.

The other is an academic doctor when they are acting or speaking in an academic capacity (which might extend as far as theologians speaking publicly on behalf of the church, for example).

Other than these settings, it tends to sound somewhat pompous to refer to such people as doctors.

I would dare say academic qualifications tend to count for little in the ethos of the policing hierarchy, and senior policemen may know that (regardless even of your own wishes) referring to you publicly as "doctor" would make you sound pompous amongst the rank and file, to the detriment of your status rather than its enhancement.

The title that would be most appropriate to use would be your title in the policing hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two slightly conflicting usages of titles here:

We've got rank titles such as "Cheif", "Lieutenant" etc that are conferred to the holder of a job.

And we've got personal titles/honorifics "Mr.", "Ms.", "Dr." that are conferred to a person based on their circumstances/achievements.

Now, if people are only ever referred to as the former, it's not unreasonable that someone might be called by their first name if they don't hold a rank title.

However, if anyone is referred to as "Mr." or "Ms." then it's perfectly reasonable to expect to be called "Dr.". As that *is* your title.

Furthermore, in a professional setting, it's generally perfectly acceptable to request to be referred to by any combination of your title, first, and last names regardless of what people generally do. Some people might choose to be judgy about it, but that's their prerogative and I wouldn't lose any sleep over it, you've earned that title, use it.

---

It might also be that people refer to you differently based on their perceived closeness. I certainly know some people who refer to their friends by their first-names but if they don't know someone go with their full title just to play it safe. I'm not saying this *is* the case, but it's something to bare in mind. Again, you're well within your rights to ask to be referred to with your title.

---

I also think that the answers referring to "most people think Drs have medical experience" are laughable. Outside of a hospital setting, nobody in a professional environment is going to assume that Dr X is a medical doctor. I think your average person is more than aware that other doctorates exist. Even if they do assume that you are a medical doctor, it doesn't actually matter if you're not working somewhere where that misunderstanding would cause a problem.

Comment: "if anyone is referred to as "Mr." or "Ms." then it's perfectly reasonable to expect to be called "Dr." - I'd disagree on that. Social titles are not in the same category as academic titles. Is a random cashier supposed to know that I'm not just a mister for them, I'm a doctor? That's clearly pompous nonsense.

Comment: @Davor - I wouldn't expect a random cashier to call me anything other than my first name. That being said, there's a reason you're often asked for your title when registering with shops/hotels etc. and that's so that they can use your correct title. Having a PhD confers a significant social status and it's well earned. You have the title and you're entitled to ask people to use it. It's no different to a married woman correcting people who call her "Ms.". The same can't necessarily be said for titles you have just because of your job.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to women by their first name is typical casual sexism.

Just shoot him a short note saying you'd prefer to be Dr. Jennifer Smith in the future.

Comment: Or Ms. Smith, which may be more appropriate for the context and get less pushback.

Comment: I'll think twice before jumping and saying this is sexism. Check the other answers and the context. Being called Dr. in a Law Enforcement environment makes few to no sense, and thus why OP was called Supervisor (as that *is* a relevant title in the field).

Comment: Implying that calling a women by their first name is sexism, but it isn't when calling men by their first name .... is textbook definition sexism.

Comment: I dont know about the casual sexism. That said, you worked hard for that PhD and it should be reflected in your title. I agree with the second half, that whenever someone uses the wrong prefix in an hyper-professional setting (like an awards ceremony) they should be notified of their mistake.

Comment: Referring to women by their first name _when men with equivalent qualifications are referred to by title_ is typical casual sexism.

Comment: It *might* be casual sexism, but it might not... It depends on context we're missing here. It might just be that the guy in question views her as a personal friend. You're jumping straight to an accusation that there's not enough evidence for in the question.